# What's the best way to detect a Hot Reload in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-6.0

What's the best way to detect if .razor page is Hot Reloaded?  I'm currently doing something like this:

```
<MyTypicalContent></MyTypicalContent>

<!-- add this line -->
<div>@(RefreshOnHotReload())</div>                


@code {
    DateTime last = DateTime.Now;
    bool HotReloaded = false;

    public async Task<string> RefreshOnHotReload() {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        HotReloaded = ((now-last).TotalSeconds > 5.0); // assumption!
        if (HotReloaded) {
            await do_something_wonderful();
            last = DateTime.Now;
            return $"Hot Reload: {now}";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the only way is to check the assembly version.

Comment: @Nicola Interesting... Which "assembly version" changes after a hot reload? `asm.GetName().Version`, `ModuleversionId`, etc... seem to remain unchanged.

Comment: Have you checked each DLL files ? Try to compare date & time.

Comment: Ah I see. It is more complicated but I suppose that would work. Or I could just watch a dir like `proj/bin` for changes...